# Use Arduino pro micro to program pro mini?

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, arduino-pro-micro

So I got a pro micro and 2 pro minis and I was wondering if I could use the pro micro to program my minis? Anyone has any links or guides on how to do this, if at all possible?

Comment: Other than the normal ArduinoISP guides?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will still work but I will suggest you [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Leonardo-as-Isp/step5/Target-Atmel-Microcontroller-1-Atmega328p-burning-/).
As arduino micro is Leonardo compatible and you r two arduino minis are based on atmega328. You should be able to use the tutorial posted above to use micro as programmer for the two mini.
Hope that helped.